# Microsoft Excel : Two IF logics in one cell with different outcomes

Tags: excel, algorithm, ms-office

I have an Excel document in which prices and discounts are calculated for different products and customers..

1. Cell D8 is the cell where the outcome of a small algorithm is
   printed. The algorithm and cell D8 will be made invisible to be read out in the workversion of this exceldocument.
2. Cell B8 should be the value that an employee reads out as definitive value to mark on his paperwork.

**What I want to do in words:**

I want the output of the algorithm (in D8) to be printed in B8 unless two specific conditions are true. Let's call these IF1 and IF2.

The problem is that if IF1 is true, it should print a different value, than if IF2 is true. If either are false, they should just print the output of the algorithm, so that means copying the value of D8.

**What I want in logic functions:**

IF1 looks like this:

```
IF(AND(B3<=75;D8>5);5;D8)
```

IF2 looks like this:

```
IF(B5<=175;50;D8)
```

**Whats the problem?**
If I paste either one of those formulas in the B8 cell they work fine.
I haven't been able for the life of me on how to combine the two into one cell.

Can anyone shine a light please? :(

Kind regards,
Willem

Comment: I can tell you now that you need a nested `IF()`.  But it's not yet clear what should happen if both IF1 and IF2 are true.  Please give a table of all 4 possibilities, and what the outcome in B8 should be for each.

Comment: `=IF(AND(B3<=75,D*>5),5,IF(B5<=175,50,D8))` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help and interest.

It comes down to this:

IF1=True, IF2=False, then: print 5 if the AND logic is true, or print D8 if the AND logic is false.

IF1=False, IF2=True, then: print 50 if B5 is greater than or equals 175, or print D8 if B5 is less than 175.

IF1=True, IF2=True, then: print 5 if the AND logic is true, or D8 if the AND logic is false.

IF1=False, IF2=False then: print the value of D8

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(B3<=75,D8>5),5,IF(B5<175,50,D8))
```

You can accomplish what you are after with nested IF statements as shown above. In pseudo-code, it means

```
if (B3 <= 75) and (D8 > 5) then
 answer = 5
else
 if (B3 < 175) then
  answer = 50
 else
  answer = D8
 end if
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

That did the trick.
For anyone else watching this after Googling.

Learn to get creative with using logicfunctions as IF NO or IF YES answers.

Thank you guys for helping. Much appreciated.
Wish you guys the best!